# Unchecked Cast warning: cast Object to Generic

Tags: java, object, generics, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a DoublyLinkedList with genenerics.
According to [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), the argument of remove() method must be an Object.

If I try to cast Object o to T data, I will get the warning: Unchecked Cast: 'Java.lang.Object' to 'T'.

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
        T data = (T) o; // warning here
...
}
```

To avoid this, I have to suppress the warning by "@SuppressWarning("Unchecked")"

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean remove(Object o) {
        T data = (T) o;
...
}
```

My understanding is every T is an Object but not every Object is a T. That's why it shows the warning.

But what if when I use my DoublyLinkedList class, I'm 100% sure the Object argument is a T, is there a way to avoid the warning or @suppresswarning is the only choice here?

If my assumption is not correct, what is the correct way to cast an Object to a T?
Thank you.

Comment: For `remove`, do you *need* the object to be a `T`? You're presumably only using `.equals` which works on all objects and presumably will return false if the object passed in is not in fact a `T`.

Comment: So the real question is: Do you really need to cast to `T` for the implementation of `remove()` to work? If you compare using `equals()`, the answer is no, so what in *your* implementation requires the cast to `T`? If you eliminate the cast, you eliminate the warning, and the need to suppress it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo and Andreas: thank you for your comments but are there any differences between head.data.equals(o) and head.data == o?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. My implementation is wrong. I should use .equals() as you guys mentioned because == checks for reference comparison, not content comparision. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid the `@SuppressWarning` would be to have a field holding the element's class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> ... {
    ...
    private final Class<T> elementClass;

    ...

    public DoublyLinkedList(Class<T> elementClass) {
        this.clazz = elementClass;
    }

    ...
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        T data = elementClass.cast(o);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good to know this to avoid SuppressWarning, but I think using .equals() is better.

Answer (score 0):

As Silvio and Andreas mentioned in the comments.

No need to cast Object to T, instead, we just need to use .equals() for comparison.

My initial implementation is to use == operator to compare the object. This is wrong because == is used to compare the reference not the content.

Comment: What about `instanceof`? **instanceof** checks if an object is an instance of a class. Example: `if (obj instanceof ThisClass)`